# google map key for gmap v3

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a question regarding googlemap api version3, 
basically we are already using google map api driving distance and geo code functionality within our internal web application,  for  that we are paying for google on our google map key,

so my question is on old google map v2  we did have to encrypt our map key and post back to google in order to get work geocode or driving distance,   and at the same way do we still have to encrypt the google map key with map api V3 ?   or we dont need the map key for google map V3 ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)

> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key to
>   function correctly. However, we strongly encourage you to load the
>   Maps API using an APIs Console key which allows you to monitor your
>   application's Maps API usage

Comment: how about if i am going to use this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: do we need to include our api key or something ?

Comment: as the previous comment says, only if you want to be able to monitor you application's Maps API usage. If you are not interested in that, then leave it out...

Comment: so even though for commercial users like me we should not include the api key or clientid or signature paramerts in ?

Comment: I do not think it will hurt to include it. I suspect once you start to hit a certain amount of google maps "hits", they are going to want it so that they can charge you.